# Multiple view controllers with different orientations

Tags: ios, swift

### Explanation

I have a game that runs in landscape, and I'm trying to send an email, also, in portrait mode.

**Basically:**

- if the actual view is `GameViewController` = `.Landscape`;
- if the actual view is `MailViewController` = `.AllButUpsideDown`.

---

### Demo code

I built this code below, but I'm having an issue with it:

- Mail isn't being called when touching the screen.

You can download this code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rr4kv5ve4zwsamw/AAAm6-mMVFlZzYeEYqIgVPgga?dl=0).

**GameScene**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        //Mail
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("openMail", object: nil)

    }
}
```

**GameViewController**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set view size.
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .Landscape
        } else {
            return .Landscape
        }
    }
}
```

**MailViewController**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import MessageUI

class MailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Register mail observer (so I can call from GameScene)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MailViewController.openMailController), name: "openMail", object: nil)
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }
}

//Mail
extension MailViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func openMailController() {

        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self //extremely important to set the mailComposeDelegate property, not the delegate property

        self.presentViewController(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Luiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your provided code is that observer in MailViewController class view did load method is not called. So Observer is not set to receive any notification.

Also you didn't called segue anywhere in your code to call MailViewController.

**Solution: By using Delegate Method**

GameScene class updated:

```
    import SpriteKit

    // Protocol 
    protocol  gameSceneDelegate  {
        func openMail()
    }

    // Protocol 


    class GameScene: SKScene {

        // Delegate
        var sceneDelegate : gameSceneDelegate?

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            /* Called when a touch begins */

            //Mail
    //        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("openMail", object: nil)

            // delegate method called on receiving touches
            self.sceneDelegate?.openMail()

        }
    }
```

GameViewController class updated:

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit

    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Set view size.
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

            // Delegate Confirmation

            scene.sceneDelegate = self

            // Configure the view.
            let skView = view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }

        override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
                return .Landscape
            } else {
                return .Landscape
            }
        }
    }

    // Delegate Method Implementation

    extension GameViewController : gameSceneDelegate{
        func openMail(){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openMail", sender: self);
        }
    }
```

Mail View Controller:

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit
    import MessageUI

    class MailViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //Register mail observer (so I can call from GameScene)
    //        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MailViewController.openMailController), name: "openMail", object: nil)

            self.openMailController()
        }

        override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
                return .AllButUpsideDown
            } else {
                return .All
            }
        }
    }

    //Mail
    extension MailViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

        func openMailController() {

            let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self //extremely important to set the mailComposeDelegate property, not the delegate property

            self.presentViewController(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Last change in storyboard:

click segue connecting GameViewController and MailViewController and change identifier to - openMail or whatever you want to keep

Comment: I just did as you said, but it's crashing when I touch the screen. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/8JOfR9j.png) you can see how the storyboard is.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change identifier to openMail. I updated as you said, but it's still crashing. You can see the storyboard screenshot [here](http://i.imgur.com/UaKz4YS.png).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rw11chmklpgnv8g/mailTestNotWorking.zip?dl=0

I have updated the project. See if this is working

Comment: Hi! It worked, but when I touch "Cancel", in order to get back to my game, it won't get back. I tried to set a segue to go back to `GameViewController` (as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/fPOOLMy.png)); and as you did with `openMail` in `GameViewController`, I called `backToGame` in `MailViewController` (as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/XnJx448.png)), but when I touch "Cancel" in Mail, a black screen shows up.

Comment: there is no need to setup another segue from your mailviewController you can dismiss your presented view controller from the mailviewController on the same segue. 
Please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem

Comment: but as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/XnJx448.png), it's supposed to be dismissed when clicking "Cancel", but nothing happens. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: in order to not create another question for only this "dismiss problem", I kept asking you here. I'll accept the answer, but please keep helping me here.

Comment: delete back to game segue from your backToGame method and place the dismiss view controller method inside backToGame method

Comment: like [this](http://i.imgur.com/VxtsuaR.png)? I just did, but it kept going to a black screen.

Comment: hi! I don't know why this isn't working. I guess 'MailViewController' is being dismissed, but something happens to `GameViewController` that it won't show up (not even the fps counter in the bottom right corner), only a black screen.